# Are there six functors for twisted D modules?

Tags: d-modules, geometric-representation-theory, flag-varieties

Is there a notion of holonomic D module which admits the six functor formalism in the world of *twisted* D modules?

---

Recall that twisted D modules on $X$ are well-defined for any $T$ torsor $\tilde{X}\to X$, see e.g. [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/37926/what-is-a-twisted-d-module-intuitively). The twist is by a character $\chi$ of the torus. Of course the most important example of this is when $X=G/B$ is the flag variety of a semisimple algberaic group.

Comment: You can think of twisted D-modules on X as ordinary D-modules on $\tilde{X}$ which are $\chi$-monodromic along the fibers. A twisted $D$-module is holonomic if and only if the corresponding $D$-module on $\tilde{X}$ is holonomic. In this way one should be able to deduce the correct functoriality behaviour.